# How to remove window frame in game made in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

So all my problem is illustrated in the title. When the game is launched and (for example) the windowed mode is chosen at the Configuration Window, how can I remove a window frame (where "minimise" and "close" buttons situated)?
P.S. Maybe there were a solution before I asked but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Pretty sure you can change that in the `Player Settings` part of the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity has some built-in [Unity Standalone Player command line arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html). One of them is

> **`-popupwindow`**: Create the window as a a pop-up window, without a frame.

---

Either create a new link to your `standalone_app.exe` file and add the parameter `-popupwindow` to the target path.

Or you can use the approach from [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/13009/borderless-window-in-standalone-player.html):

open the Windows `Editor` app (or any text editor) and do

```
/path/to/your/built/app.exe -popupwindow
```

and save it as `.bat` file. If you now doubleclick that it opens without the Window bar.

You can than later convert this to an exe using e.g. [BatToExe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bat-to-exe/)

Answer (score 1):

Update to Comment/Answer

You can change it to be `Exclusive Fullscreen` in the `Player Settings` under the `Resolution and Presentation` section.

[image]

Comment: but this will always make it fullscreen not a windowed resultion without window bar